# PHP Cryptography Class Issues

Tags: php, static, cryptography

I'm having a few issues regarding this Cryptography class. I am new to PHP, and I'm sure this is a minor syntax issue, but can anyone point me in the right direction? The code does not work at all at the moment.

Here is the code

Cryptography.php

```
class Cryptography
{
    # the key should be random binary, use scrypt, bcrypt or PBKDF2 to
    # convert a string into a key
    # key is specified using hexadecimal
    # use either 16, 24 or 32 byte keys for AES-128, 192
    # and 256 respectively
    private static $key = pack('H*', "I-AINT-SHOWING-YOU-MY-KEY-LOL");
    private static $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);

    public static function encrypt($plaintext)
    {
        # --- ENCRYPTION ---

        # create a random IV to use with CBC encoding
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

        # creates a cipher text compatible with AES (Rijndael block size = 128)
        # to keep the text confidential 
        # only suitable for encoded input that never ends with value 00h
        # (because of default zero padding)
        $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

        # prepend the IV for it to be available for decryption
        $ciphertext = $iv . $ciphertext;

        # encode the resulting cipher text so it can be represented by a string
        return base64_encode($ciphertext);
    }

    public static function decrypt($ciphertext_base64)
    {
        # --- DECRYPTION ---

        $ciphertext_dec = base64_decode($ciphertext_base64);

        # retrieves the IV, iv_size should be created using mcrypt_get_iv_size()
        $iv_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, 0, $iv_size);

        # retrieves the cipher text (everything except the $iv_size in the front)
        $ciphertext_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, $iv_size);

        # may remove 00h valued characters from end of plain text
        return mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $ciphertext_dec, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv_dec);
    } 
}
```

Test.php

```
    require_once('Cryptography.php');

    $text = 'This is the string I am going to encrypt' . "\n\n";

    echo $text;

    $encrypted_text = Cryptography::encrypt($text);

    echo "{$encrypted_text}\n\n";

    $decrypted_text = Cryptography::decrypt($encrypted_text);

    echo "{$decrypted_text}\n\n";
```

Comment: _'It doesn't work'_ is __not__ an adequate problem description.

Comment: This is one of the error messages I've been getting

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in path\Cryptography.php on line 10"

where line 10 is the line the key is declared

Comment: Inside your functions definitions you need to change `$iv_size` and `$key` variables to `self::$iv_size` and `self::$key` as they are of the same class - you probably get a notice that they are not defined now.

Comment: Thanks @n-dru, I've done what you said. The same error message about line 10 still appears.

Comment: Static variables may only be initialised with a literal or constant. [Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: Okay, so I've changed the key and iv_size variables from private static to private. I'm still getting the same error message about the unexpected opening bracket.

Comment: By the way, you aren't authenticating your ciphertexts.

Answer (score 0):

static $key cannot be an output from another function. It must be literal. You can change `$key` to some function, like `create_key()` and return that `pack()` output. All `$key` must be then changed to `self::create_key()`. And the same concerns `$iv_size`, it needs to be converted to `self::get_iv_size()` as well.

```
private static function create_key(){
    return pack('H*', "I-AINT-SHOWING-YOU-MY-KEY-LOL");
}
private static function get_iv_size(){ 
    return mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
}
```

Comment: Other than setting the `$key` to a class variable and accessing it as such, why would they include another function to do what they were doing before? Can you explain that?

Comment: Yes, it can be made directly by a function

Comment: Im asking why they need to, not how

Comment: You can't use an expression (i.e. a function) in the definition. You can use them in the constructor, of course.